# Simplifying $\sin^{-1}(\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question on $$\sin^{-1}(\cos x)$$

Since $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac \pi 2 \pm x)$, the above expression can simplify to either $\frac \pi 2 + x$ or $\frac \pi 2 - x$. This seems like a contradiction.

What's the problem here?

Comment: The $\arcsin$ function is defined (usually) to map $[-1, 1]$ into $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\ \frac{\pi}{2}]$, to make it a function.

Answer (score 5):

There is no contradiction. Keep in mind that the $\arcsin$ function is a map from $[-1,1]$ to $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$, in order to avoid ambiguities. So:

- if $x\in[0,\pi]$, then $\arcsin\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)=\frac\pi2-x$;
- if $x\in[\pi,2\pi]$, then $\arcsin\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)=-\frac{3\pi}2+x$.

Outside the interval $[0,2\pi]$, use the fact that your function is periodic with period $2\pi$.

Comment: should not the second be $\color{red}{+}\frac{\pi}{2}+x$?

Comment: @farruhota No, because then we would be outside the range $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: but now it is $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$?

Comment: @farruhota You're right! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: +1. For showing how to get different expressions of $x$ for different intervals of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin^{-1}(\cos x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)\right)$$

and then recall that

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin \theta) =\theta \iff \theta\in \left[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right] $$

otherwise we need to adjust the result adding a suitable $k\pi$ term.

We can also use

$$\sin^{-1}(\cos x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi}2+x\right)\right)$$

and in that case we obtain different range for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

You have to play with these relations/definitions:

- $y=\arcsin x\iff \sin y=x\;\text{ AND }\;-\frac\pi2\le y\le \frac\pi2$,
- $y=\arccos x\iff \cos y=x\;\text{ AND }\;0\le y\le \pi$,
- $\arcsin x+\arccos x=\frac\pi2$,
- $\sin(\arcsin x)=x$ BUT only $\;\arcsin (\sin x)\equiv \begin{cases}x\\[0.5ex]\frac\pi 2-x\end{cases}\mod 2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\mp(y+2\pi n),y\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Then:
$$\begin{align}\arcsin(\cos x)&=\arcsin(\cos [\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\mp(y+2\pi n)])=\\
&=\arcsin(\sin (y+2\pi n))=\\
&=\arcsin(\sin y)=\\
&=y.\end{align}$$
Example 1: If $x=300^\circ$, then $300^\circ=-90^\circ+(30^\circ+360^\circ)$ and:
$$\arcsin(\cos 300^\circ)=30^\circ.$$
Example 2: If $x=-300^\circ$, then $-300^\circ=90^\circ-(30^\circ+360^\circ)$ and:
$$\arcsin(\cos (-300^\circ))=30^\circ.$$
Example 3: If $x=180^\circ$, then $180^\circ=90^\circ-(-90^\circ+0^\circ)$ and:
$$\arcsin(\cos (180^\circ))=-90^\circ.$$